# View the file system of iPad/iPhone to verify saved files

Tags: ios, filesystems, sandbox

I would like to be able to view the file system of my actual iPad/iPhone to verify that files are being written correctly. I can do this using the simulator by navigating to Users/*me*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/*specific app*/Documents. Here I can see all of the files and data I have written from within my app.

I would be really helpful if anyone knows of an app or some way of viewing the file system of my apps **WITHOUT JAIL BREAKING**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at iExplorer:
http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Also, look at this question:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54682/easiest-way-to-browse-iphone-filesystem

Comment: A friend pointed me to i-Fun-Box after I posted this. The second link you gave talks about it.

Comment: Also, check this link out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548029/copy-a-file-from-iphone-sandbox-to-desktop?rq=1

Comment: iexplorer cannot read dropbox and box data. It reads my app and Exel app. Is there a way to not allow this.

Comment: in early days before ios8, it was possible to see all Data of all apps with iExplorer, but since ios9 (you can read more about this on iexplorer website) you just see apps with files, if:
**- the app is sharing files `UIFileSharingEnabled (Application Supports iTunes file sharing) `** over iTunes

or

**- you're developing a app at this moment (then you can see also the sandbox folder of your app (especially it means, you see app folders which are installed with developer certs on your device (e.g. over xcode))**

Answer (score 5):

Strongly recommend [iFunbox](https://www.i-funbox.com/), take a look at LifeHacker review [here](http://lifehacker.com/5914638/the-best-desktop-file-explorer-for-iphone). Easy to use and you can even access your iPhone over WiFi. No jailbroken required too.

Comment: I agree, this is the best solution I've seen for what I needed. The answer that Victor Ronin posted included a link to a question where iFunbox was being discussed. It has become an indispensable tool for development.

Answer (score 2):

You should try DiskAid: http://www.digidna.net/diskaid which is way better than iExplorer. You can connect to your iPhone or iPad via Wi-Fi and USB and browse your iOS file system, app sandboxes and it supports multiple device and simultaneous file transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost 100% sure this is not possible without a jailbreak (at least not on the device itself). If it works on the simulator, then it should be saving correctly on the actual device. If you need to verify it, just read the file from your app, and turn it into an NString, and NSLog it.

Then you will know if it is working.

Cheers.

EDIT

Of course, as others have mentioned, there is iExplorer, but you have to view the files on a Mac. And it won't show system files.

Comment: I actually have an app I've been testing for awhile and I wanted to take a look at its file system.

Comment: Do you just need to check one file, if so, you will have to add code to read it. There is no file manager like on Android. And you can't get one from anywhere. Even the developer tools does not allow this.

Comment: iExplorer easily reads and writes the parts of the file system that you are probably interested in but it doesn't let you see the system directories. You can see the files that belong to all of the apps on the device. This is NOT the iExplorer in the App store -- it's an app that runs on the MAC and you download it from macroplant.com.

Comment: Yeah, iExplorer works, but I was talking about on the device itself. :) I'll edit thought to be clear.